# Correct terminology for the joint probability density function?

Tags: probability, notation, terminology

Suppose I have a joint PDF of two random variables given as:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y).$$ 
Both of the random variables vary from $0$ to $\infty$.
I integrate variable $Y$ to some arbitrary values, i.e.,
$$f_X(x,0\leq y\leq 5).$$
Now I know that $$f_{X}( x,0\leq y \leq \infty)$$ can be termed as marginal PDF of $X$. But how should I define $f_X(x,0\leq y\leq 5)$? Is it the marginal PDF of $X$ when $Y$ lies in 0 to 5. Does $f_X(x,0\leq y\leq 5)$ qualify to be called as PDF as $$f_X(0\leq x \leq \infty ,0\leq y\leq 5)\neq1$$

Comment: $f_X(x,.<y<.)$ is confusing notation. Marginal of $X$ is just $f_X(x)=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dy$

Comment: Looks like you are asking about the conditional density of $X\mid a<Y<b$ for some $a,b$, which is given by $$f_{X\mid a<Y<b}(x)=\int_a^b\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{P(a<Y<b)}\,dy$$

Comment: Suppose it is a bivariate normal distribution f(x,y) and I integrate y, not from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, but from $0$ to $5$. What should be the terminology, should that be now just PDF of $x$ when $y\in\{0,5\}$?

Comment: Not $y\in\{0,5\}$, but $y\in(0,5)$. What you are asking for is the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $0<Y<5$. See my last comment.

Comment: So now the bivariate PDF is conditional distribution of X given that 0<Y<5. It is not PDF of X conditional on 0<Y<5, because then it needs to have integration over range of X as 1 , which is not the case.  Am I correct?

Comment: It *is* the pdf of $X$ conditioned on $0<Y<5$. So integrating it over all $x$ such that $0<y<5$ should result in $1$.